# does a new object created in share is immediately available to consumer or not in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In this documentation link it is mentioned that objects will be immediately available to consumer https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-intro.html

In this documentation link it is mentioned that objects will not be available immediately https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-provider.html#general-data-sharing-considerations-and-usage

Which one is correct? Does Snowflake knows the truth or not on this??

Answer (score 0):

Any objects that you add to a share are instantly available to the consumers accounts who have created databases from the share. For example, if you add a table to a share, users in consumer accounts can query the data in the table as soon as the table is added to the share.
But you have to understand that you need to grant usage, etc on the new object to the share; that's what is meant by "available".

Comment: As availability (able to see the object) and consume (able to see the data in object) are completely different contexts that created this confusion.

Comment: @RamaKrishna I think you are referring to this sentence? "A new object created in a database in a share is not automatically available to consumers." That's because "To make the object available to consumers, you must use the GRANT <privilege> … TO SHARE command to explicitly add the object to the share."

Comment: @FelipeHoffa How about this statement in former link "New objects added to a share become immediately available to all consumers, providing real-time access to shared data." -- this is true only in the case of data added to tables right? Not all objects

Comment: I think "New objects added to a share become immediately available" means immediately after "use the GRANT <privilege> … TO SHARE command to explicitly add the object to the share"

Answer (score 0):

A Share is an Account Level object which contains nothing and is not available to anyone unless you "connect" it to

- Objects you want to share
- Accounts you want to share it to
- Privileges needed to share them

A consumer will not see the share unless a share is assigned to it as an inbound share, this is managed by ACCOUNTADMIN.
A provider role with with sharing capabilities or ACCOUNTADMIN can create an outbound share.

From the consumer side the share itself is not useful unless a Database is created based on that share. Once made available the data is a read-only live data source to the consumer.